# unable to set direction right to left in arabic text

Tags: arabic, right-to-left, arabtex

I need to insert arabic text.
It works fine but text display is from left to right. How can I deal with that.

```
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\setmainlanguage{french}

\setotherlanguage{arabic}

 \newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script = Arabic]{Simplified Arabic}

 \begin{document}

\begin{vcenterpage}

{\large\textbf{\textarabic{ملخص} }}\\

\noindent\rule[2pt]{\textwidth}{0.5pt}

\begin{Arabic}

 \end{Arabic}

 {\large\textbf{

 \begin{Arabic}

 الكلمات المفاتيح: التسويق الالكتروني، السوق

 \end{Arabic}

  }}

 \noindent\rule[2pt]{\textwidth}{0.5pt}

  \end{vcenterpage}

 \end{document}
```

Best regards

[image]

Comment: You need to post your full code, please, starting with `\documentclass{}` and ending with `\end{document}`. You might need to set it in `\textarabic{}` though.

Comment: yes ! I shall use `\textarabic{}` instead of `\begin{Arabic}  \end{Arabic}`

Comment: now I need that the text is displayed at the right of page, not like french and english phrases

Comment: Your code is still not functional. Or minimal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I created an example for you since yours wasn't functional, and it seems that setting your arabic text within an arabic environment gives you what you want (RTL starting on right side of page):

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setmainlanguage{french}
\setotherlanguage{arabic}
 \newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script = Arabic]{Simplified Arabic}

\begin{document}

1. \textarabic{الكلمات المفاتيح: التسويق الالكتروني، السوق.} \\

\begin{Arabic}
2. 
 الكلمات المفاتيح: التسويق الالكتروني، السوق.

\end{Arabic}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\hspace*{\fill} \textarabic{الكلمات المفاتيح: التسويق الالكتروني، السوق}` 
works also

Comment: yes or just plan `\hfill` instead of `\hspace*{\fill}`.